# Parsing XML with Python ignoring parts

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm having difficulty parsing a particular style of XML.

The XML file looks like:

```
<channels>
    <genre type = blah1>
        <channel name="Channel 1">
            <show>
                <title>hello</title>
            </show>
        </channel>
        <channel name="Channel 2">
            <show>
                <title>hello</title>
            </show>
        </channel>
    </genre>
    <genre type="blah2">
        <channel name="Channel 3">
            <show>
                <title>hello</title>
            </show>
        </channel>
    </genre>
</channels>
```

So my problem is as follows:

```
channelList = rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]")
howManyChannels = len(channelList)


for x in range(1, howManyChannels):
    print x
    print rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]["+str(x)+"]").get('name')
    for y in rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]["+str(x)+"]"):
        print y.findtext('title')
```

This gets to Channel 2 and then errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    print rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]["+str(x)+"]").get('name')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Why doesn't the code:

```
for y in rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]["+str(x)+"]"):
```

include the 3rd channel, why is it being isolated as it is in another genre tab? How do I change the code to accommodate for this?

I'm trying to store in lists what channels go with what shows.

UPDATE:
I don't understand why

```
channelList = rootElem.find(".//channel[@name][3]")
```

produces the error even outside of the loop.

```
url = 'myxmlurl.com/xml.xml'
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"Accept" : "application/xml"})
u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
tree = ElementTree.parse(u)
rootElem = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: Indentation matters. We can't comment on your code if it's not correctly indented.

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code as posted isn't syntactically valid, because it isn't indented. However, the root of your problem is that you are iterating using `range`.

Instead of:

```
channelList = rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]")
howManyChannels = len(channelList)


for x in range(1, howManyChannels):
```

Do:

```
channelList = rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]")
for channel in channelList:
    pass #whatever
```

This way, you don't need to search again for the channel.

Also, your search "doesn't work" because  there is no channel element with the name `"3"`. Try searching for `"Channel 3"`.

Comment: Ok but changing the code to your above code wont allow the following code `print rootElem.find(".//channel[@name]["+str(x)+"]").get('name')` to work as x is required to be a number not an object. Sorry for the indentation error, that was my fault on the initial post, the code is not reflected that way.

Comment: @JavaWizKid Did you not read this all the way through? You don't need to search for the channel again, because you have it right there.

Comment: ok thanks for the loop fix. That doesn't fix the problem, if I just use `channelList = rootElem.find(".//channel[@name][3]")` outside of a loop and print it it gives the error.